# Store and manage site page templates centrally in one place and use it on all subpages

Tags: library, template, sitepages

I would like to create a template for site pages and use it on all subwebsites.
A template is located on the topmost website in the standard library for pages. I get this template when I use the drop-down menu on the start page and want to create a new page. There are the three templates that are displayed by default and my own. This works on the website as usual, but this template should be usable on all subsites. I don't want to have them redundant in the sharepoint, that leads to errors and more effort if the template should be edited.

Can you think of a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a native way to do that with just a single copy of the templates at the top level.

However, templates are nothing more than a page that is saved in the Templates folder of the SitePages library, so theoretically, you could create a Flow in Power Automate that is triggered whenever a page is created or modified in the SitePages library, and if that page is in the Templates folder, then copy it to the Templates folder in each of the subsite's respective SitePages libraries.

This would mean that if someone altered a template at the subsite level, it could potentially get stomped on the next time the same template was updated at the top level and then propagated.

Comment: Great, thanks for your answer. This solution is simple and good, so simple and pragmatic that I didn't even think of it.